# Why is it "dont" instead of "dans lequel" in this context?

Tags: grammaire, choix-de-mot

In *Le mythe de Sisyphe*, Camus writes:

> Ces parfums d'herbe et d'étoiles, la nuit, certains soirs où le cœur
> se détend, comment nierais-je ce monde dont j'éprouve la puissance et
> les forces?

Why isn't it "ce monde dans lequel j'éprouve la puissance..." because I've always thought *dans lequel* was for when you wanted to say "in which" in the sense that you're physically within the object. In the sentence I thought Camus was trying to say "how could I deny this world in which I experience power and force" so I don't understand why he used *dont*. Could someone please clarify this for me?

Comment: dont is **of or about which**. not in which. [...] how would I deny this world the power and forces of which I feel? Modernized; [...] how would I deny this world whose power and forces I feel.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

L'antécédent de *dont* est *ce monde*, c'est donc des forces et de la puissance du monde qu'il s'agit.

On peut retourner la proposition « ce monde dont j'éprouve la puissance et les forces » comme suit :

J'éprouve la puissance et les forces **de** ce monde (pas *<s>dans</s> ce monde*) :

> *I feel the power and the forces **of** this world*

et pas

> *I feel the power and forces **in** this world*

Voir la [BDL](http://bdl.oqlf.gouv.qc.ca/bdl/gabarit_bdl.asp?id=2904).

Comment: "how would I deny this world whose power and forces I feel", is not: I feel the power and forces of this world. Le "dont" crée une proposition subordonée.

Comment: @Lambie Bien sûr. Mon propos n'était pas de traduire mais d'expliquer le passage de **dont** à **de**.

Comment: Mais tu détruis la phrase. Pour re-écrire, il faut garder le sens en français. Tu l'as changé complètement....ce monde dont j'éprouve la puissance et les forces=ce monde qui a la puissance et les forces que j'éprouve.

Comment: Je ne détruis rien du tout. Si tu ne comprends pas le sens de la phrase en français, je n'y peux rien.

Comment: "J'éprouve la puissance et les forces de ce monde* n'est pas du tout: **comment nierais-je ce monde dont j'éprouve la puissance et les forces**? Si'il faut dire que je ne comprends pas le français pour critiquer ma critique, on est très mal parti.

Comment: Je suis d'accord sur ce point. Je te remercie donc de cesser tes commentaires. Tu es bien sûr libre de proposer une autre réponse.